# Last of element of list is being truncated in python?

Tags: python, list, element

```
!curlhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/elements1_20.txt -o elements1_20.txt
elements = open('elements1_20.txt', 'r')
elements_lines = elements.readlines()

count = 0

for line in elements_lines:
    elements_lines[count] = line[:-1].lower()
    count += 1

print(elements_lines)

['hydrogen', 'helium', 'lithium', 'beryllium', 'boron', 'carbon', 'nitrogen', 'oxygen', 'fluorine', 'neon', 'sodium', 'magnesium', 'aluminum', 'silicon', 'phosphorus', 'sulfur', 'chlorine', 'argon', 'potassium', 'calciu']
```

As you can see the last element of list is not showing in full? can somebody help me to do so.

Comment: Because you are truncating your lines by "line[:-1]". How to correctly remove EOL, see the mentioned link above.

Comment: Thanks bro. I did it.